# How to make an infinite horizontal scroll on list (li) elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I am looking to achieve is to make the items in the list continue scrolling even at the last item in both directions. i.e: Let it continue to scroll starting from the first OR last item all over again. I have worked out the HTML and CSS but don't know what method to use in js/jquery. I'd really appreciate any help or a good pointer. 
Here is the HTML

```
<html>
<div class="container">
<ul class="horscroll" id="autoscrollR">
<li>
<a href="#myGallery" data-slide-to="0" data-tooltip="acci"><img 
class="img-thumbnail" 
src="http://dummyimage.com/96x96/f0f0f0/626262.png&text=1" >
                                     </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#myGallery2" data-slide-to="1" data-tooltip="aiico"><img 
class="img-thumbnail" 
src="http://dummyimage.com/96x96/f0f0f0/626262.png&text=2">
                                    </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#myGallery3" data-slide-to="2" data-tooltip="asaba"><img 
class="img-thumbnail" 
src="http://dummyimage.com/96x96/f0f0f0/626262.png&text=3">
                                    </a>
</li>
 ...........
</ul>
</div> </html>
```

And the CSS is used is very basic for an example:

```
.container{
max-width: 100%;
}
.horscroll {
display: -webkit-inline-box;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
margin:10px;
}
ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;

}
li {
display: list-item;
text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
.img-thumbnail {
margin: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
border: 1px solid #;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Now the Js function to use is where I am stuck.

Here is the [FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/2h8wzvsn/)

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for something like this:-

```js
var bgWidth = 350; //Max-width of <li> you would like to set.
var scrollPos = Math.ceil($('body').width() / 20);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').width(bgWidth + $(window).width());
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollLeft() >= ($('body').width() - $(window).width())) {
      $(window).scrollLeft(1 + scrollPos / 4);
    } else if ($(window).scrollLeft() == 0) {
      $(window).scrollLeft($('body').width() - $(window).width() - scrollPos / 4);
    }
  });
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('body').width(bgWidth + $(window).width());
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.horscroll {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.img-thumbnail {
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="horscroll" id="autoscrollR">
    <li>
      <a href="#myGallery" data-slide-to="0" data-tooltip="acci"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://dummyimage.com/96x96/f0f0f0/626262.png&text=1">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#myGallery2" data-slide-to="1" data-tooltip="aiico"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://dummyimage.com/96x96/f0f0f0/626262.png&text=2">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#myGallery3" data-slide-to="2" data-tooltip="asaba"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://dummyimage.com/96x96/f0f0f0/626262.png&text=3">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#myGallery3 " data-slide-to="2 " data-tooltip="asaba "><img class="img-thumbnail " src="http://dummyimage.com/96x96/f0f0f0/626262.png&text=4 "></a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#myGallery" data-slide-to="0" data-tooltip="acci"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://dummyimage.com/96x96/f0f0f0/626262.png&text=5">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#myGallery2" data-slide-to="1" data-tooltip="aiico"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://dummyimage.com/96x96/f0f0f0/626262.png&text=6">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#myGallery3" data-slide-to="2" data-tooltip="asaba"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://dummyimage.com/96x96/f0f0f0/626262.png&text=7">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#myGallery3 " data-slide-to="2 " data-tooltip="asaba "><img class="img-thumbnail " src="http://dummyimage.com/96x96/f0f0f0/626262.png&text=8 "></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi @Jennis Vaishnav, thanks for your contribution and it goes a long way but I was looking at something more of this nature here: https://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/bGbjZdz   but the thing is, this one is working with a click and not scroll